# Sparql: list Steven Spielberg's films on dbpedia.org

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web, dbpedia

Example output, use http://dbpedia.org/page/Steven_Spielberg as example

format: film_name, screen_player(zero to more, separated by "|"), producer(zero to more, separated by "|")

Example output 1: Hook_(film), Frank Marshall|Kathleen Kennedy|Gerald R. Molen, James V. Hart|Malia Scotch Marmo

Example output 2: Jaws_(film), Richard D. Zanuck|David Brown, Peter Benchley|Carl Gottlieb

[image]

End point
http://dbpedia.org/sparql

My query so far, which is far from the example 1 and example 2.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select
?filmName,
(GROUP_CONCAT(?producerName ; SEPARATOR = "|") AS ?producerNames),
(GROUP_CONCAT(?screenPlayerName ; SEPARATOR = "|") AS ?screenPlayerNames)
where {
?film dbpedia-owl:director dbres:Steven_Spielberg .
?film rdfs:label ?filmName .

optional {        
?film dbpprop:screenplay ?screenPlayer .
?screenPlayer foaf:name ?screenPlayerName .         
}

optional {
?film dbpedia-owl:producer ?producer .
?producer foaf:name ?producerName .
}
}
order by
?filmName
```

**My question**: basically, I need to display all Steven Spielberg's movies like the two examples above.

Comment: This is not really clear. What do you mean with "output as samples"? In SPARQL you can do sampling with something like "order by rand() limit 10". However, while I used this with Fuseki, it was not working with the dbpedia endpoint: I got always the same 10 results :(

Comment: Have you tried 'sample'? Like enridaga I don't understand your question.

Comment: @enridaga, I need to display all Steven Spielberg's movies in the same format as sample 1 & sample 2.

Comment: Ah, got it. Answered.

Comment: In your sample output, it looks like you're making pipe (`|`) delimited strings.  What happens if any of the fields contain `|` character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbres: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT
( CONCAT ( SAMPLE(?filmName) , " , ", 
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?producerName ; SEPARATOR = "|"), " , ",
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?screenPlayerName ; SEPARATOR = "|")
         ) AS ?formatted )
WHERE
{
    ?film dbpedia-owl:director dbres:Steven_Spielberg .
    ?film rdfs:label ?filmName .

    optional {        
        ?film dbpprop:screenplay ?screenPlayer .
        ?screenPlayer foaf:name ?screenPlayerName .         
    }

    optional {
        ?film dbpedia-owl:producer ?producer .
        ?producer foaf:name ?producerName .
    }

    FILTER (lang(?filmName) = 'en')
}
GROUP BY ?film
```

[Try the query out](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbpprop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbres%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28%20CONCAT%20%28%20SAMPLE%28%3FfilmName%29%20%2C%20%22%20%2C%20%22%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FproducerName%20%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%22%7C%22%29%2C%20%22%20%2C%20%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FscreenPlayerName%20%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%22%7C%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%20AS%20%3Fformatted%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20dbpedia-owl%3Adirector%20dbres%3ASteven_Spielberg%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FfilmName%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optional%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20dbpprop%3Ascreenplay%20%3FscreenPlayer%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FscreenPlayer%20foaf%3Aname%20%3FscreenPlayerName%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20optional%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20dbpedia-owl%3Aproducer%20%3Fproducer%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproducer%20foaf%3Aname%20%3FproducerName%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FfilmName%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Ffilm&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The bulk of the work is in the `SELECT` expression, which `CONCAT`s the various elements together.

The other change is `GROUP BY ?film` which collects together the elements so there is one row per film. We have to `SAMPLE(?filmName)` because of this: there may be more than one name. (In fact most films have multiple names due to different languages, which we suppress with a filter)

Comment: I doubt it will be a problem in this scenario, but since the separator is `|`, it might be a good idea to replace `|` in the strings with something else (e.g., `\|`).